# What does RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ ?path=$1 [QSA,L] mean in my .htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I need to create rewrite in nginx as is done in my .htaccess and there are some lines which I don't completely understand.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond % !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ ?path=$1  [QSA,L]
```

Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: This is incorrect: `RewriteCond % !-f`

Comment: I suspect that is not correct, but it works and works for a long time. I just started to understand the current configuration and correct it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RewriteCond % !-f` seems incorrect rule condition and is always evaluating to true.

This rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ ?path=$1  [QSA,L]
```

Is **matching any URI with trailing slash** and internally rewriting to `/?path=uri-without-slash`

So for ex: an URI `/foo/` will be rewritten to `/?path=foo`

- QSA - Query String Append
- L = Last rule

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

**UPDATE:** Change that incorrect condition to:

```
# request is not for a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# request is not for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ ?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very mach Anubhava. I am very sorry, cannot + to you reputation. One more question - is incorrect RewriteCond compromising sacurity?

Comment: That incorrect condition might give you unexpected results sometime. I suggest changing it as per me edited response above.

Answer (score 1):

It means if the request isn't to a file, then rewrite everything before a trailing `/` into `index.php?path=` followed by what was previously matched.

It should be the last rule (`L`) and it should append the query string (`QSA`), as opposed to discarding it because of the replacement's query string.

Comment: Thank you very mach Alex for your answer.