# .htaccess issue, getting url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm having an issue.

I have a vagrant box which is hosting me a url (learnphp.dev)

below is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It seems every page I go to is the home page. You can find my code below:

https://github.com/mikerodham/simple-router/tree/master

I'm pretty new to PHP so just starting out with simple things. If anyone could provide any help that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace RewriteRule with this:

```
RewriteRule^(.+)/$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260571/what-does-rewriterule-path-1-qsa-l-mean-in-my-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Let index.php to echo `$_GET['uri']` ( help debugging ) and try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to help the issue either, :/ Could it be something with my virtual environment?